# Is storing data about life events out of OpenStreetMap's scope?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is it possible to model event data (e.g. life events at a concert hall that is marked by location) as part of OpenStreetMap metadata?

If yes, what is the relevant data schema and REST API?

If no (since this may be considered out of scope), are there other prominent collaborative projects that deal with the gathering of (pointers to) events in a common, machine-readable data format?

So far I have seen several aggregators (e.g. apps) that use OpenStreetMap for (the more "static") geographic data and add own proprietary layers for storing (the more "dynamic") event data (e.g. when a life concert takes place or when a street is closed to traffic due to construction), etc., on top. I am wondering if such proprietary layers are strictly needed with all the open data out there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [openstreetmap](http://help.openstreetmap.org/)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I can see you point, but please consider that it is also about the REST API of OpenStreetMap (hence the corresponding tag). Thx for the link. I will re-ask there, if this question is going to be closed.

Comment: This is two questions as one = should I store information about transient events on OSM, and if so, what's the API for it. I believe the answer to the first part of that would be a strong "no", which then leads to the next bit about an API to submit something that isn't natively supported. Had your question included details of the API you were calling, and code that you're calling it with, with details of how it isn't working for you, then I could see that more relevant here. OSM does have it's own [question & answer site](http://help.openstreetmap.org/) that would be a better place for asking

Comment: @RowlandShaw Again, I can see you point. Since MaM's answer includes additional helpful pointers, I'll accept his and thereby close the question now. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a general consensus in the OSM community, that we just add geodata about mid- long-term objects.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Best_practices

But of course, the community is very dynamical and yes there are people who contribute geodata about XXL local events (Burning man, ...) or objects with short lifetime (Xmas markets, ...) but be aware that this is controversial, esp. we lack of a unique time model:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Comparison_of_life_cycle_concepts

No idea if there are mashups that geolocate events an return the data via public API and a good license. Usually people prefer Facebook, Google+, ... so I guess it's not that easy to crawl that stuff legaly.